# Is there any difference between these two JVM settings in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

1) Click `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->JDK1.8->Edit->Default VM options`

and

2) Click `Run->Run Configurations->Java Application->VM options`.

If I set -Xmx=6G. Is there any difference between these two options in setting the RAM to be used by my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-the first 1 makes all the new Java projects using the selected Jre ect.. and iit affect the running settings if they are per default.

-but if you use directly the second method ,it will only affect the running not the creation of the next projects.

and if you've noticed , when u do (2nd methode):

```
Run->Run Configurations->Java Application->VM options
```

you can choose the default environnement selected by the first method.

Answer (score 1):

On is, as it's named, the *default* options to use. The other applies only to *just that* launch configuration, and you might have many more.